# How does try_files work with fast_cgi?

Tags: nginx

I'm a newbie to Nginx, and saw guides telling me that if I do this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

(simplified example from https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/).

Then what I understand is that if a client asks for:

```
/uploads/myavatar.gif/ascript.php
```

And `ascript.php` is not found, FastCGI will start to check up-in-the-path to see whether some part actually matches a file. In this way, assume:

```
/uploads/myavatar.gif
```

exists because someone uploaded it, that file would be treated, having the remaining part of the $uri in the PATH_INFO. So, '/script.php' would be the value in PATH_INFO for a ¿gif file?¿or perhaps a b*tc*y PHP file with another extension?.

So the proposed solution to not fall on such caveat was to use:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

**What I understand** is that `try_files` will check every alternative file specification and:

- The last specification **must** exist, or a 500 will be thrown.
- The last specification must be an error code preceded with equality sign.
- The last specification must be another @location declared (which could be, e.g., a "_pass".

**What I thought I understood** but seems I don't understand it correctly is: The files are checked against a `root` directive (i.e. try_files works by checking the nearest `root` directory and appending each file specification). So, what I thought is like this:

```
root /var/nginx/www;
#assume this directory exists
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

#each uri would be tested like root$uri, root$uri/, or fail with =404
```

But if that's the logic, which under these new light I don't see it's right, then:

- A .php would be tested for existence for a given root.
- If it's not file nor directory, FAIL with 404.
- If it did not fail, pass the same path to the fastcgi.

**My question is**:

- How does try_files work when evaluating every file alternative AND there's a proxy_pass or fast_cgi pass? It seems I have the wrong impression about how it worked.
- Who takes precedence between having a `root` directive and a `fastcgi_pass` directive, regarding file check? (also i'm interested on the possibility on having `proxy_pass` for python-based projects which mount -each- a local server like `gunicorn`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_files` is a simple file existence checker. It simply checks, if the file (`$uri`) or directory (`$uri/`) exists.

If neither of those exists, it then returns 404 error.

If the file exists, execution is continued to next line, that is, `fastcgi_pass` or `proxy_pass` or anything else that has been configured.

So, the behavior of `try_files` is independent of whether `fastcgi_pass` or `proxy_pass` exists.

`try_files` always uses the `root` directive for checking the file existence.

Then, the solution to the original problem of possible exploits via .gif files is to include this directive in the PHP location block:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

You also need to set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to false in php.ini.

This way PHP gets the correct PHP file name as the script to execute.

Comment: So the try_files only works as long as both applications (nginx and fastcgi) are in the same filesystem?

Comment: If you have FastCGI files in a separate directory, you should specify that directory path with `alias` directive inside the `location` block for that FastCGI.